# Shopping Cart Price Rule, Magento 1.9

Tags: upgrade, shopping-cart-price-rules

We just updated from 1.8 to 1.9 and now our Shopping Cart Price Rule isn't working correctly.  The rule is to give 10% off orders $300 and more.  What it is doing now is giving 10% off on any item even if it's under $300.  The conditions state: If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:

Subtotal  equals or greater than  $300.00

As I said, this worked fine before the update.  Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: Have you re-applied price rule?

Comment: Hi Tim. Not sure how to do that. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: Sorry, thought you are talking about catalog price rules.

Comment: Yes, I am, and yes I did. Made the old one inactive and recreated a test one with the same parameters. Still didnt work.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the rule configuration tab and the action tab?

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix

Answer (score 2):

For a shopping cart price rule the discount is distributed over all products, you can force to only apply the discount on products over $300 by adding a condition in the Actions tab:

**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)**

```
Row total in cart equals or greater than 300
```